# Variable changed after initialization not reflected in interface

Tags: java, android, interface

Sorry about the bad title. I really cant think of anyway to word this interesting issue.

I have a rather large class going on, and in that class I have an interface (lets call it foo).

foo is set by the user after the class has finished its intialization. (i.e. someClass.setFoo(randomInterface).

At the top of the class I have a few premade interfaces for this exact reason, and the user will pick one for the particular instance. Lets use the above example.

in my someClass.setFoo I'll have something like this

```
public final void setFoo(MyInterface interface){
    foo = interface;
}
```

and MyInterface interface will have a call in it, say executeFoo.

```
interface MyInterface{
    void executeFoo();
}
```

Finally I have my randomFoo interface.

```
MyInterface randomFoo = new MyInterface(){
    @Override
    void executeFoo(){
        Log.d("Some Stuff here?","Maybe?");
    }
}
```

My issue is when I call the MyInterface.executeFoo() method later (after the user has set the interface correctly, assume for this sake they have), I never see this log popup.

I can't for the life of me figure out why, and I've gone so far as to clean the build (android studio), uninstall it and start over, still to get nothing.

If i by pass the set and just set foo to be randomFoo before the initialization, it works just fine.

So I suppose I am confused on why this is not working, and if I am just misunderstanding something about java.

Below is a brief overview of the class I am working with (Using the example stated above).

In my parent class to this, assume there is a call that goes like so

```
// ... other parent stuff
SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.setFoo(SomeClass.randomFoo);
someClass.executeFoo();
// ... some random parent stuff after
```

The SomeClass

```
public class SomeClass{
    public final static MyInterface randomFoo = new MyInterface(){
        @Override
        public void executeFoo(){
            Log.d("Some Stuff here?","Maybe?");
        }
    };

    public final static MyInterface randomFoo1 = new MyInterface(){
        @Override
        public void executeFoo(){
            Log.d("RandomFoo1","RandomFoo1");
        }
    };

    private MyInterface foo;

    public SomeClass(){
        init();
    }

    private final void init(){
    //  This does nothing of relevance here
    }

    public final void setFoo(MyInterface newFoo){
        foo = newFoo;
    }

    public final void executeFoo(){
        foo.executeFoo();
    }

    interface MyInterface{
        void executeFoo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve] displaying the exact issue. (also `interface` is a reserved word)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `If i by pass the set and just set foo to be randomFoo before the initialization`? Whatever you've shown, works as you expected. Not familiar with Android - so is the `Log` part correctly set up?

Comment: `randomFoo` is not `static`. It should be accessed by `someClass.randomFoo` not `SomeClass.randomFoo`. Otherwise I don't see any issues here. What is the specific problem?

Comment: I just executed this code as a normal java program (changed Log.d() to a sysout) and it worked fine as I'm pretty sure Log.d() works fine. Can you share what exactly leads to logs not printing in logcat ?

Comment: my stupidity. I was going through the code late last night and found that I was setting someClass.setFoo twice, with the second time doing something different than I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turns out that in the parent class, I was calling someFoo.setFoo multiple times, setting foo to different MyInterfaces. I fixed that and it works just fine.